# Pygame where Sprite Skates

Tags: pygame, slide, sprite

I'm having difficulty making my sprite skate.

The thing is my sprite should be sliding until it hits something like the border of the screen or a block. Also, this should be done when the sprite is on ice and if the sprite isn't on ice then the sprite should walk. So if the person presses up once, then the sprite will skate until it hits something that will stop its movement.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Like I was able to make my sprite slide but for a short distance
but that's not the sliding I want lol
I want it that distance doesn't matter 
rather it should be that the sprite slides until something stops it

Comment: You'll need to post at least the relevent part of code up here, I have no idea what you have done or how, I can't help you till I do unfortunatly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you currently have your code, but a general template would be:

```
# main loop
while True:
  for each object:
      update(framerate)
      render()

# skater code
class skater:
    moving = True
    speed = [0,0]
    x = 0
    y = 0

    def update(framerate):
        # check for collisions
        if collision:
            self.moving = False

        # move the skater
        if self.moving:
            self.x += self.speed[0]*framerate
            self.y += self.speed[1]*framerate
```

`moving` will be set to true then an arrow key is pressed.
where `speed` is decided by what arrow keys have been pressed (`-` for left and up, `+` for right and down)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cEpp44NS
Here's my code
It's kind of buggy, because the sprite will slide a short distance then stop moving altogether
mind looking it over?

Comment: you need to inherit from `spite` not `state`, http://pygame.org/docs/tut/tom/games5.html should help a bit.

Comment: Actually, I did that because I have a character class that is the Sprite and I have walking.py and standing.py which make the sprite move (in animation) and I want to do something similar with skating.py which is the code I showed you

Comment: @bluesplay106 hmm I see, well there's nothing obvious wrong in this code, the bug must be somewhere else. I might try looking in `self.character.onIce()`, sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code at http://pastebin.com/cEpp44NS you're doing things like:

```
self.speedX1 *= (self.ice * self.normal_friction)
```

Which is going to very rapidly reduce `self.speedX1` (especially since `self.ice` is set to 0.01)

From what you've said, it sounds like you don't want the speed to be decreasing at all whilst sliding, so try just removing this code.